# How to correct the java.lang.NullPointerException in my SQLite login?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have encountered my second issue when using SQLite to create a login/register activity for my app. I am following an online tutorial, I think I understand it all and I have followed what he did exactly, it worked for him, but my application crashes. 
Here is the function within my database:

```
 public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseOperations dop){
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL};
    Cursor CR = SQ.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    return CR;
}
```

The issue occurs once I have clicked the login here is the code for the button:

```
 public void SignInOnClick(View view){
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    int status = b.getInt("status");
    if(status == 1){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please wait...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        email = Email.getText().toString();
        password = Password.getText().toString();
        DatabaseOperations DOP = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
        Cursor CR = DOP.getInformation(DOP);
        CR.moveToFirst();
        boolean loginstatus = false;
        String NAME = "";
        do
        {
                if(email.equals(CR.getString(2)) && (password.equals(CR.getString(1))))
                {
                    loginstatus = true;
                    NAME = CR.getString(0);
                }
        }while(CR.moveToNext());
        if(loginstatus)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Login Successful \n Welcome"+NAME, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

The error reads as the following according to logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Add complete log snippet and link of tutorial also

Comment: Link to tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsbYu-j6_TE

Comment: the complete log snipped is too long to post, anything in specific I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Bundle object without checking for nullity first.
And that is the reason why your app is crashing.

Try changing your code as such:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int status = b != null ? b.getInt("status") : 1;
if(status == 1){
```

Comment: Just tried that, now my button doesn't seem to do anything, and this is the error code I get:



04-20 01:12:00.527    3094-3094/com.example.wolfe_000.final_final_zeno D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier﹕ KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
    in android.widget.EditText{1b2ec516 VFED..CL .F...... 32,505-736,554 #7f080043 app:id/editText2}
    0: sent at 11513512000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=11513512, downTime=11513384, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }

Comment: can you post your other code? did you setup a listener already?

Comment: i chose to use the XML onClick method, which code do you need? :)

Comment: just cause it's a bit long to post into a comment

Comment: try adding this on your XML for the button.
android:clickable="true"

Comment: if that doesn't work , try adding a listener programmatically using
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button); button.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: It's still literally doing nothing, I don't think it's an issue with the actual button.

Comment: can you change the code I have given you to:
int status = b != null ? b.getInt("status") : 1;

I just used 0 as an example.  Changing that to 1 will always execute your
if condition.